# how to calculate variance between means in r

Tags: r

I think this is not a difficult question, but I just got stuck. For two independent datasets (vectors), original values x and predicted values y, I use *t-test(x,y,var.equal)* to calculate the mean values of these two datasets. How to calculate the difference between the means?
|mean of x - mean of y|/|mean of x|   or   |mean of x - mean of y|/|mean of y|?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you use `t.test` to calculate mean values? Wouldn't it be better to use `mean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first asuming this as your data:

x: original values x1,x2,x3...xn

y: predicted values y1,y2,y3...yn

then simply:

```
VarmeansX <- var(x)
VarmeansY <- var(y)
```

so you have in *VarmeansX* and *VarmeansY* the variance of each data samples, so in order to know what is the difference just do

```
VarBetween <- VarmeansX - VarmeansY
```

so you will have a positive or negative number, if the case is the first then the variance in your *original* values is **greater** than the *predicted* values,etc.